# How to stop scrapy from paginating the pages with repetitive records?

Tags: django, pagination, scrapy, web-crawler

I tried to crawl a website whit pagination by scrapy, and it was ok! But, as this website gets update and new posts are added to this website, I need to run my code every day, so each time I run my code, it crawls all the pages. Fortunately, I'm using django and in my django model, I used

> unique=True

So there are no duplicate records in my database, but I want to stop the pagination crawling as soon as it finds a duplicate record. how should I do this?
here is my spider snippet code:

```
class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'news'
    allowed_domains = ['....']
    start_urls = ['....']
    duplicate_record_flag = False

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="next page-numbers"]/@href').get()

        news_links = response.xpath('//div[@class="content-column"]/div/article/div/div[1]/a/@href').getall()

        for link in news_links:
            if self.duplicate_record_flag:
                print("Closing Spider ...")
                raise CloseSpider('Duplicate records found')
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_item)

        if next_page and not self.duplicate_record_flag:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)


    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = CryptocurrencyNewsItem()
        ...
        try:
            CryptocurrencyNews.objects.get(title=item['title'])
            self.duplicate_record_flag = True           
            return
        except CryptocurrencyNews.DoesNotExist:         
            item.save()
            return item
```

I used a class variable (duplicate_record_flag) to have access to it in all functions and also to know that when I am facing a duplicate record?
The problem is that the spider doesn't stop in real time when the first duplicate record is founded! For more clarification: In the for iteration in the parse function, if we have 10 news_links and in the first iteration we find a duplication record, our flag wouldn't change at that moment and if we print the flag in the for loop, it will print 10 "False" values for each iteration!!! While it should be changed to "True" in the first iteration!

in other words, the crawler cralws all the links in each page in each parse!
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the spider after meeting certain criteria, you can raise the CloseSpider

```
    if some_logic_to_check_duplicates:
        raise CloseSpider('Duplicate records found') 
        # This message shows up in the logs
```

If you just want to skip the duplicate item, you can raise a DropItem exception from the pipeline. Example code from [Scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html?highlight=skip%20duplicates#duplicates-filter):

```
class DuplicatesPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        if adapter['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem(f"Duplicate item found: {item!r}")
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(adapter['id'])
            return item
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried to do the same thing, but I got a new problem, so I edited my question.

Comment: Scrapy is asynchronous. It sends a bunch of requests and calls the parse method as the response is available. For filtering duplicates, use pipelines instead of spiders.